# Easy access to Ethereum

Tags: go-ethereum

At the moment all Ethereum services seems to be running on web3.js and this requires a full node to be running, most users will never install 30+ GB to use a website or service. I my self have tried to MANY times and wasted lots of effort trying to get geth and parity to sync but here in Asia the nodes get stuck and stop syncing for some reason. Not enough peers.

-When will the light client protocol be ready?
-Why do more Ethereum websites not just serve normal webpages (rendered with web3.js server side)
-Is there anyway to get stating writing smart contract AND deploying them on the main net without a node running?

Comment: It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!

Comment: This is a legitimate problem and thus a legitimate question.  Just because there are many answers doesn't mean this is not a real problem and doesn't mean it's not worthy of a stackexchange question.  Also, the critique presupposes the author knows the answers....

Comment: that being said, you could rephrase your questions at the end to "I tried X, Y and Z, and here's why they don't meet my needs", instead of as questions.

Answer (score 3):

> -Is there anyway to get stating writing smart contract AND deploying them on the main net without a node running?

1. We have created a Geth node online at geth.b9lab.com and we are curious to see what you can do with it. It has no private key on it and can only be accessed via HTTP. We also make no assurance as to the quality of service, so let us know, we are curious.

The modules available are `--rpcapi "etc,web3,net" --lightserv 25 --lightpeers 50`.

```
| Network | TCP port |
|:--------|---------:|
| ETH     |      8546|
| Morden  |      8547|
| ETC     |      8548|
| Ropsten |      8549|
```

For instance:

```
$ curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_blockNumber","params":[],"id":1}' geth.b9lab.com:8546
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"result":"0x20b298"}
```

2. Use [Browser Solidity](http://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity/#version=soljson-latest.js) to code. You should be able to point it to our Geth, from the "Cube" tab.
3. Install the [Metamask.io](https://metamask.io/) plugin to handle your keys and sign your private transactions.

Comment: Your node seems to be offline...

Comment: Sometimes it crashes.